# Slingshot selector syntax to catch ExceptionInfo in Clojure

Tags: exception, clojure, try-catch

If I use Slingshot's `try+` and `catch`, it's easy to write a selector to match on the contents of a map:

```
(defn dosomething (throw+ {:some :data}))
(try+ (dosomething)
    (catch [:some :data] ;; recover))
```

However, if I want to use `ex-info`, that catch selector doesn't match the `ExceptionInfo`'s data:

```
(defn dosomething (throw (ex-info "A message" {:some :data})))
```

Obviously I can catch an `ExceptionInfo` or write a custom predicate to match the data, I was just wondering if I was missing something about Slingshot or `ex-info`, as I'd been led to believe they worked together more smoothly than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you want to throw an ExceptionInfo, my understanding is it's just a carrier for arbitrary data that you can just throw normally with throw+.

```
(throw+ {:some :data :msg "A message"})
```

Or if the point is that you don't want to use throw+, then I don't think there is a totally straightforward way to catch it.  You'd have to do something like

```
(catch (-> % ex-data :some (= :data)) myerr (foo myerr))
```

I don't know what the use case is for wanting to use try+ but not throw+.

Comment: I don't have a burning desire to use ex-info, it's just a few things I read (e.g. http://technomancy.us/154) led me to believe that ex-info superseded throw+, so I thought I was missing something. Apparently not, though - thanks! :)

Comment: Recent versions of slingshot actually throw ex-info exceptions